# How do I format a numeric element as currency in KnockoutJS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following routine in a script tag.

```
        for (var i = 0, j = message.Transactions.length; i < j; i++) {
        var m = message.Transactions[i];

        //m.Amount Needs to be Currency
        IndexViewManager.displayList.push(m);
    }
```

There's an element in "m" that is numeric and I want it to be displayed as currency.  KnockoutJS is being utilized to data-bind the elements if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `toLocaleString` method and pass in the currency information as a object which is one of the input parameter to the method.

```js
var number = 1234;

console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }));
```